# Anydesk not installing in Raspberry Pi 3b+ with Raspberry OS 64 bit

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, 64-bit, dpkg

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dpkg -i anydesk_6.0.1-1_armhf.deb
(Reading database ... 94130 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack anydesk_6.0.1-1_armhf.deb ...
Failed to stop anydesk.service: Unit anydesk.service not loaded.
Unpacking anydesk:armhf (6.0.1) over (6.0.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of anydesk:armhf:
 anydesk:armhf depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.16.0).
 anydesk:armhf depends on libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.20.1).
 anydesk:armhf depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1).
 anydesk:armhf depends on libx11-6.
 anydesk:armhf depends on libxcb-shm0.
 anydesk:armhf depends on libxcb1.
 anydesk:armhf depends on libpango-1.0-0.
 anydesk:armhf depends on libcairo2.
 anydesk:armhf depends on libxrandr2 (>= 1.3).
 anydesk:armhf depends on libx11-xcb1.
 anydesk:armhf depends on libxtst6.
 anydesk:armhf depends on libxfixes3.
 anydesk:armhf depends on libxdamage1.
 anydesk:armhf depends on libxkbfile1.
 anydesk:armhf depends on libegl1-mesa.
 anydesk:armhf depends on libgl1.

dpkg: error processing package anydesk:armhf (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.31.4-3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-4) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.62) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 anydesk:armhf
```

I also tried gdebi:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ gdebi anydesk_6.0.1-1_armhf.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done
This package is uninstallable
Cannot install 'libgtk2.0-0:armhf'
```

This didn´t help either:

sudo apt install -f

Answer (score 2):

Either you don't have the `armhf` architecture set up in DPKG, or you don't have `http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/buster/main/binary-armhf/` in your APT sources. Or maybe you just didn't update your system for a long time.

The former should be fixed by running  `dpkg --add-architecture armhf`.

The latter requires you to add APT sources as described [here](https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianRepository). Look specifically for a line similar to the one below, and add it if it's missing:

```
deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian buster main contrib non-free
```

Don't forget to run `sudo apt update` to pick up any changes you have made.

Comment: -bash: deb: command not found
but I think I tried these before, but let me know how I can install deb because apt install deb did not work and I can´t find a solution for it

Comment: @Badjano `deb http...` is not a command. It's a line you put in your `apt` sources list.