# Anydesk not installing in Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspberry OS 64 bit

Tags: remote, raspberry-pi-os, 64-bit, dpkg

I have followed the two fixes suggested in [question 118662](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/118662/146298).

In my case, Anydesk does not start up after installation on a PI4, Raspberry OS 64bit. - I click on the icon, a time glass replace the cursor for a couple of seconds, then ..nothing.

**re installation**

```
admin@nord:~ $ sudo dpkg -i anydesk_6.1.1-1_armhf.deb
(Reading database ... 95114 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack anydesk_6.1.1-1_armhf.deb ...
Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/anydesk.service.
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of anydesk.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
Unpacking anydesk:armhf (6.1.1) over (6.1.1) ...
Setting up anydesk:armhf (6.1.1) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/anydesk.service → /etc/systemd/system/anydesk.service.
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.69) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
admin@nord:~ $ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
admin@nord:~ $
```

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't installing arm64 deb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

64bit Raspberry Pi OS not yet supported by AnyDesk.
https://support.anydesk.com/knowledge/anydesk-for-linux-raspberry-pi-freebsd

Comment: but TeamViewer Host can be installed on it. There Preview version is running well on my Raspi 4 64bit. 
https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `arch-test` to check supported architectures. This needs to be installed from the repository `sudo apt install arch-test`. This runs a number of programs for different architectures.

Raspberry Pi OS -64 bit uses the standard Debian repositories which should have an arm64 version.

I have never used AnyDesk, but if it wanted to I would use the recommended procedure http://deb.anydesk.com/howto.html

add repository key to Trusted software providers list

`wget -qO - https://keys.anydesk.com/repos/DEB-GPG-KEY | apt-key add -`

and add "deb http://deb.anydesk.com/ all main" to your sources list.