# AnyDesk new session not appearing

Tags: remote

Currently, I am trying to setup anydesk to remote support onto a pi going to be used in kiosk mode. I have anydesk installed and setup so that I'm able to connect but at the moment unable to create a new session or open up the normal window to view the settings panel to setup the custom settings I need.

I've run through and ensured all libraries and up to date which they all are but still unable to open anydesk properly.

Comment: run: /bin/anydesk-global-settings

Answer (score 0):

I have run into similar problem; The official https://anydesk.com/en/downloads/raspberry-pi source does not seem to work on my Pi 4 (with the most current Raspberry Pi OS). I managed to make it work by following this guide https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-anydesk/ , it installs a specific version of Anydesk (also seen here https://linuxhint.com/install-anydesk-raspberry-pi/ ).

Can't really say what the problem is with the Anydesk version from the official website, just googled enough until I found a solution.

Edit: there is also something along the lines of Anydesk being not supported on 64bit, and a workaround: [Anydesk not installing in Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspberry OS 64 bit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/137284/anydesk-not-installing-in-raspberry-pi-4-with-raspberry-os-64-bit?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the responce, I followed this guide but still not getting the application to pop up. It fully installs but at Step 2on the "Running the AnyDesk Software" portion of the guide is where I'm failing. Nothings happening bar AnyDesk opening up and showing in the top right corner so I'm unable to make any adjustments to AnyDesk in terms of setting up unattended access for remote support.